# Docker image running successfully but getting connection time out

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am very new to docker.I have started learning form past 1 day.I have created one own docker image in ubuntu machine it is running successfully but when I try to access it getting connection time.Any one help me out of this problem.

**my docker image:**

```
From java:latest
MAINTAINER nithin nithinroyal@gmail.com
LABEL env=production
ENV apparea /data/app
Run mkdir -p $apparea
ADD https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/releases/download/4.32.0/gitbucket.war /$apparea
Run mkdir -p $apparea
WORKDIR $apparea
CMD ["java","-jar","gitbucket.war"]
```

command I used to run the image:

```
sudo docker run --name "nithin" -d -p 8084:8084 gitbucket
```

After running the above command I got this e32cef4a48f496b9c22ab6bf0cd03b28f51a0a119b2b3ba4815d158fd7dad45e

container also successfullt running as shown below;

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
e32cef4a48f4        gitbucket           "java -jar gitbucket…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                0.0.0.0:8084->8084/tcp   nithin
```

When I try the following command getting error

```
 sudo docker run -d -it  --name "nithin" -d -p 172.32.21.185:8084:8084 gitbucket

Error:3d13a24ac89344cfa833989672b70706163b2accd6b8cec541ffff492d63fe51
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nithin (aeba6ca0572b875897d04ca8945e16e67cb6139abc9ae95fb7b8e340ddaced9b): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 172.32.21.185:8084: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

No service is running on this port.When i try with other ports also getting same error.

Comment: @Pacifist http://172.32.21.185:8084

Comment: Does your app inside container expose any port? It looks like port inside your container is not running. I actually created a container from your dockerfile as you mentioned but there is no port running inside the container.

Comment: @Pacifist sudo docker port nithingit
I executed this command the result is 8084/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8084

Comment: Where does the `172.32.21.185` IP come from? Is there any network interface on the host listening on this IP?